# How to install a PDF file on iOS simulators launched via XCUIApplication

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest, xcuitest

Is there a way to add a file to all of the iOS simulators launched for XCUITests which were launched using XCUIApplication()? I need a way to install a test PDF file on all of the simulators (we run with parallel mode enabled so usually 3 simulators are running) before the tests are ran.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parallel test devices are the clone of the original Simulator you choose. This way, you need to manipulate with the original one only and you need to do it before the tests.
2. Simulators data is kept in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator directory. You can manipulate any of the Simulators by changing data.
3. You should find the Simulator data you need, and initialize a git repository in this folder. Then, add your PDF and see the changes compared to the initial state.
4. Finally, repeat the same changes with any script before starting the tests.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Looking for more of an automated way of doing it so that the files can be installed automatically on the sims prior to anyone running the tests.  Wondering if there is something like a command line function that could be run with Run Script phase or something?

Comment: Well, you can do anything with bash scripts, and I described you the way to find out the steps.